# Paypal with a shopping cart button in iphone

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, paypal

I'm making an app in which I need to integrate PayPal. I integrated the PayPal button, but I don't know how to add a shopping cart button, so that I can total all the products.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I did it for a sample app.  I built a cart in my app (just a simple dictionary of items that I can add to and subtract from in the normal workflow) and at the top right of the app there's a button that says "Checkout". At which point the user will be presented with a view of their cart and using the Paypal MPL library I make a request to generate a "pay with paypal" button.

```
UIButton *button = [[PayPal getPayPalInst] getPayButtonWithTarget:self andAction:initiatePayment andButtonType:BUTTON_294x43];
```

Then in my Initiate Payment method I fill the cart.

```
(void)initiatePayment {
    [preapprovalField resignFirstResponder];

    [PayPal getPayPalInst].shippingEnabled = TRUE;
    [PayPal getPayPalInst].dynamicAmountUpdateEnabled = TRUE;
    [PayPal getPayPalInst].feePayer = FEEPAYER_EACHRECEIVER;

    PayPalPayment *payment = [[[PayPalPayment alloc] init] autorelease];
    payment.recipient = @"test_11111111_biz@testing.com";
    payment.paymentCurrency = @"USD";
    payment.description = @"Cart Checkout";
    payment.merchantName = @"Fake Store O Stuff";
    payment.subTotal = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"10"];
    payment.invoiceData = [[[PayPalInvoiceData alloc] init] autorelease];

    payment.invoiceData.invoiceItems = [NSMutableArray array];
    for(invoiceItem cartItem in Cart.Items) {
        PayPalInvoiceItem *item = [[[PayPalInvoiceItem alloc] init] autorelease];
        item.totalPrice = cartItem.totalPrice;
        item.name = cartItem.name;
        [payment.invoiceData.invoiceItems addObject:item];
    }
    payment.invoiceData.totalShipping = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"2"];
    payment.invoiceData.totalTax = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"0.35"];

    [[PayPal getPayPalInst] checkoutWithPayment:payment];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm don't think that Apple will allow you to do this.  They don't allow for other means of payment other than In-App Purchase.

Comment: That is only true for services & subscriptions. Read the guidelines.

Comment: In practice I do not think that is true. For example, Amazon is not allowed to have its bookstore in the Kindle app.

Comment: Ross : I'm pretty sure you've proven yourself wrong IE amazon has it's own app where you can buy plenty of products without using the In-App purchasing system.

Comment: Also, why would PayPal build and release an iOS library if it couldn't be deployed on the platform?

Comment: But my question is, apart from paypal, can we use or build our own API for transactions?